# Windows 8.1 crashes after every update

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, crash, windows-update

Something nasty started going on with Windows. Every time it does an update, it crashes on update. Every time it says something like this:

`error C0000034 applying update operation (somefilename)`

Every time it is different error name and filename. After that only thing I can do, is restore system. But if it does another update, it will crash again.

Is there a way to fix updates somehow? For now I disabled updates, but it would be better to have updates and not crash it like that.

P.S. The interesting thing is, that my friend called me few weeks ago saying similar thing happening to his Windows. Then I thought he maybe forced PC to shutdown during updates. But now this thing is happening to my Windows. It looks like there is some bug in updates.

**Update**

Running `sfc /scannow`

outputed this:

`Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Running this:

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

Hangs at 20%..

Comment: Have you ran the DISM and SFC tools recently to check the integrity of your system files?

Comment: No I haven't. I ought to try it, when I get back home. Maybe it will tell more about what is causing this.